# Bootstrap making webkit transition not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter shelf that slides out:

http://jsfiddle.net/dragonfreak1000/jx2jqa39/4/

But if I add Bootstrap to it, the actual widget does not animate:

http://jsfiddle.net/dragonfreak1000/jx2jqa39/5/

I happen to know the widget is an iFrame, but I can't find what in the bootstrap code would stop it from functioning. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id = "tweet" class="hidden">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitter" data-widget-id="544215204960038912">Tweets by @twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
<img id="twitter-button" src="//codepixl.net/img/Twitter_alt_4.png" align="right"></img>
```

CSS:

```
#tweet {
    position:fixed;
    width:500px;
    z-index:999999999999;
    left:calc(100% - 500px);
    transition:left .4s;
    -webkit-transition:left .4s;
    -o-transition:left .4s;
    -moz-transition:left .4s;
    -ms-transition:left .4s
}

#tweet.hidden {
    left:calc(100% - 0px)
}

#twitter-button {
    cursor: col-resize;
    position:fixed;
    border-top-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    left:calc(100% - 75px);
    border:2px solid #fff;
    z-index:99999999999999;
    height:75px;
    transition:left .4s;
    -webkit-transition:left .4s;
    -o-transition:left .4s;
    -moz-transition:left .4s;
    -ms-transition:left .4s
}

#twitter-button.out {
    left:calc(100% - 575px)
}
```

JS:

```
$("#twitter-button").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("out");
    $("#tweet").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

How can I fix this without removing bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the class `.hidden` which is also used in Bootstrap (to set an element to `display: none`). If you rename it to for example `.tweet-hidden` in your html, css & js it is fixed. See http://jsfiddle.net/ckuijjer/t11c8qgo/

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid now... I can't accept for 7 minutes but when I can I will.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't feel stupid, it's those tiny things that can take you several hours to finally find, where a lucky bystander might see it instantly. Trust me, I've been there several times :)